# Ionic 2 onDidDismiss() saves even when cancel() button is pressed

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm having an issue with my Ionic 2 app. I've so far built a list page of items, and each item there navigating to a detail page. At the detail page, you can edit and choose to save or cancel any changes. Save is working great.

The issue is `onDidDismiss()` function saving the data even when the close function doesn't/shouldn't pass the data back to the detail page. Here's the relevant code.

DETAILS.ts

```js
openModal() {
  let data = this.user;
  let editDetailsModal = this.modalCtrl.create(EditDetailsModal, data);

  editDetailsModal.onDidDismiss((data) => {
    if (data) {
      // this.saveItem(data);
      console.log("Data =>", data)
    }
    //console.log("Data =>", data)
  });
  editDetailsModal.present();

}

saveItem(data) {
  this.user.push(data);
}
```

EDITDETAILSMODAL.ts

```js
saveModal() {
  let data = this.user;
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
  //console.log(this.user)
}

close() {
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

EditDetailsModal page has a form to edit the data passed to it. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Even when calling an external save function, it just made a mess of the app. Happy to do a plunkr if this isn't enough information.

Ionic Info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

Comment: why not just check if data == undefined ?

Comment: code seems all-right. Problem could be others. Provide plunker or check is your close() method being called.