# Ionic modal remembering checkbox selection even when cancel or close is selected

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I open a modal with a list of checkboxes (all checked), uncheck some of them, then when I cancel the modal and reopen it again the checkboxes are unchecked even though I cancelled.

StackBlitz [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wvwjuq?file=pages/film-modal/film-modal.ts)

I'm trying to use a list of checkboxes instead of a select component because I want a 'Select all' button.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670895/ionic-2-ondiddismiss-saves-even-when-cancel-button-is-pressed) similar issue but it is unanswered.

I want to know why the selection is persisting? How do I get it to forget the selection when the modal is dismissed? (Unless the user selects Save, but I haven't implemented that yet).

Fairly new to all this, so any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying the values of the model in the service because you're not cloning the object, you're using a reference to it.

The problem is in the following line:

```
this.filmListCopy = this.filmService.getFilmList();
```

You can make a deep copy like this:

```
this.filmListCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.filmService.getFilmList()));
```

Cheers